# How can I import a spreadsheet using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, spreadsheet

I am having trouble importing a spreadsheet using Rails and the roo gem and keep getting a `bad URI(is not URI?)` error.  I think this is a simple question that I just can't figure out how to do, but how do I properly upload and access the file.  Here is my current code:

controller.rb

```
def import
    if request.post?
      Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
      xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(params[:file])
      p s.cell(1,1)
    end
  end
```

html

```
<%= form_tag("", method: "POST", class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true) do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= file_field_tag :file, accept: 'xls,xlsx' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit_tag("Import", class: 'btn btn-default') %>  
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: try this `Roo::Spreadsheet.open(params[:file], extension: :xlsx)` or `Roo::Spreadsheet.open(params[:file], extension: :xls)`

Comment: just tried that.  I get this error: can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String.

Comment: you need pass path in `Roo::Spreadsheet.open(data.tempfile.path)` in my case,  or something else. `params[:file]` contain file with metadata not only file.

Comment: You need to save file somewhere first, either via temp file as @Monk_Code proposed or using paperclip/ other gem.

Comment: I want to use the tempfile, as I don't need the file anymore once it is uploaded.  Data.tempfile.path does not work for me.  How can I access that data variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I had to do was access the path through the params file.  The code is below:

```
Roo::Spreadsheet.open(params[:file].path, extension: :xlsx)
```

Comment: where did you add this code? in the controller, view?